# coloring a segments of a curve when using stat_function in ggplot

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I have a plotted a z-curve, and have used `geom_segment`to color areas underneath the curve.

I have plotted the z distribution using

```
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-3, 3)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = dnorm)
```

[image]

I would like to color the segments of the curve so that the color of the curve matches the color on the x-axis beneath it.

Since I'm using `stat_function`, I feel like there is  less of an opportunity to modify it's characteristics.

Has anyone attempted a similar feat and found a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dnorm_segment <- function(x, min = 0, max = 1) dnorm(x)*ifelse(x>=min & x<=max, 1, NA)
zero_segment <- function(x, min = 0, max = 1) ifelse(x>=min & x<=max, 0, NA)
plot_both <- function(min, max, colour) 
{
  args <- list(min = min, max = max)
  list(
    stat_function(fun = dnorm_segment, col = colour, size = 3, args = args, n = 1001),
    stat_function(fun = zero_segment, col = colour, size = 3, args = args, n = 1001)
  )
}

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-3, 3)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm) + 
  plot_both(-3, -2, "purple") +
  plot_both(-2, -1, "yellow")
# + etc
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful answer, I'm really impressed. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunatelly with ggplot2 you need to subset (divide it on segments manually) the data before use it. We would like to see this option integrated directly on ggplot2